# AWS - Elastic IP will Connect Private IP?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, static-ip-address, elastic-ip

I have an account in AWS, created local instance windows 2012 R2 standard edition. tried to configure Elastic (Static IP) IP to Local instance example like http://localhost:8080 to http://elasticip:8080 if it is possible to configure on AWS ??

Comment: It is automatically routed I suppose.

Comment: what is your question ? you want to assign a elastic ip to ur ec2 instance, correct ?

Comment: yes, i want to assign elastic IP to my instance.how do I redirect?

Comment: Arora20: please explain., I don't have knowledge in AWS.